# Migrating URL rewrite rules from Apache to IIS

Tags: .htaccess, php, iis

Currently, I am having issues with IIS server.

When I try to do a login call to my controller (Slim library) the returned value is the base `./index.php` file.

The code surely works. I developed the code on Apache environment. I have a live hosted version on an Apache server also, so I suspect the problem can only be from IIS configuration.

This is what I have in `web.conf`

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite fall back rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This is what works on the Apache server in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  !^$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

The last line is not needed, and I already used the IIS tool to convert `.htacces` to `web.config`, but still the behaviour was the same even though the rules were a bit different in the `<rewrite>` zone.